# Attempt to re-install Civi 5.46 results in 'CiviCRM Installed'

Tags: installation, civicrm-home

I am attempting to re-install Civi 5.46 on Drupal 7.89. I have wiped out and re-created the database, deleted Civi files, caches etc. The civicrm.settings.php file has been wiped out. I can find no trace of CiviCRM yet when I attempt to re-install it, when I click on 'You must configure CiviCRM' I get a screen that says CiviCRM is installed.

What am I missing?

CiviCRM 5.4.6
Drupal 7.89
MySQL 8
PHP 7.4

CiviCRM is definitely not installed. Why does it think that it is?

Comment: Did you uninstall the drupal module? If there's still an entry in drupal's `system` table where it says the module has status=1 then it will be in an inconsistent state. You can also try clearing drupal cache and see if that helps.

Comment: Good point on the cache. I did try that though and was unsuccessful. Thanks for the tip regarding the system table.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a couple of tables were hiding in the drupal database. Some easy MySQL and the problem was fixed

```
use drupal;
drop table civicrm_group_roles_rules;
drop table civicrm_member_roles_rules;
flush privileges;
```